# How to correct the output of this jquery code?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, viewport

This code should print:

1. if the screen width is < 740 or is 740.
2. if the screen width is > 740 and the screen width is < 1065
3. if the screen width is >1065 or is 1065
4. if the screen width is >1389 or is 1389

But it always shows 2 or 3 randomly when the 4th condition is true.
whats the problem in here? Take a look at the console.

https://codepen.io/code_alex/pen/xJLwpq

```js
var screenWidth = $(window).width();

if(screenWidth < 740 || screenWidth == 740) {
  console.log("1");
} else if(screenWidth > 740 && screenWidth < 1065){
  console.log("2");
} else if(screenWidth > 1065 || screenWidth == 1065) {
  console.log("3");
} else if (screenWidth > 1389 || screenWidth == 1389) {
  console.log("4");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Side note: `<=` is less than or equal.  `>=` is greater than or equal.

Comment: `$(window).width()` is not the screen width, it's the window width.

Comment: The screen width is `screen.width`

Comment: Put `console.log(screenWidth)` before the `if`.

Comment: still doesnt work.. any ideas?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, chances are you should reconsider scrapping `jQuery` altogether here and utilize the `@media` query in CSS instead. Just a thought though, I don't know what exactly you want to do

Comment: I want to load a specific ammount of pictures from instagram API. They have to fit into the grid optically. So CSS wouldn't be a solution.

Comment: Your third `else if` statement essentially reads `if (screenWidth >= 1065) console.log("3");` Because of this, you will never reach the final `else if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions set correctly would look like below.

Consider [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) rules unless you really need that input in JS / jQuery.

```js
var screenWidth = $(window).width();
console.log(screenWidth);

if(screenWidth <= 740) {
  console.log("1");
} else if(screenWidth > 740 && screenWidth <= 1065){
  console.log("2");
} else if(screenWidth > 1065 && screenWidth <= 1389) {
  console.log("3");
} else if (screenWidth > 1389) {
  console.log("4");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Additionnaly, you should look for [common breakpoints](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/).

Comment: Thank you so much! I have to do that with jQuery because I'm loading a specific amount of pictures from Instagram API.

Answer (score 0):

Once one branch of an `else if` is true then the execution will end, rather than checking to see if another is also true.  By your logic, if you have a `screenWidth` of `1400` then `screenWidth > 1065 || screenWidth == 1065` is true, so you don't reach the `screenWidth > 1389 || screenWidth == 1389` check.

You could revise your code to:

```
var screenWidth = $(window).width();

if (screenWidth <= 740) {
  console.log("1");
} else if(screenWidth > 740 && screenWidth < 1065){
  console.log("2");
} else if(screenWidth >= 1065 && screenWidth < 1389) {
  console.log("3");
} else if (screenWidth >= 1389) {
  console.log("4");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do

```
var i,warr=[0,740,1065,1389],
    w=screen.width;
for (i=0;warr[i]<=w;i++){}
console.log(i);
```

@Barmar: thanks for the hint re: `screen.width`!